# syntax "variable = variable = variable;" whats happening?

Tags: java, variables, red-black-tree

Okay so I'm reading some code about RedBlackTrees. And I noticed this line "v1 = v2 = v3 = v4;" and I understand something like "v1 += v2" (add v2 to the current value of v1) and "v1 = v2" (create a reference from v2 to v1) etc.

```
public void insert( AnyType item )
{
    current = parent = grand = header;
```

But I'm curious to what is happening in the memory/references with current = parent = grand = header;

http://faculty.washington.edu/moishe/javademos/REDBlack/RedBTree.java

Edit : 10:46 PM

I still have to wait 10 minutes to approve questions, sorry for the wait ladies and gents.

Comment: It should be noted that that code should be considered a proof-of-concept or a demonstration, but it's *definitely not* production quality proof. For example `current` (and related fields) should really be local variables in the methods that use them.

Comment: yeah I'm just getting my head around whats going on, so I can implement the removal method (haha), thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that the value of `header` is assigned to the value of `grand` which is assigned to the value of `parent` which in turns gets assigned to `current`. In the end, the 4 variables hold the same value; this idiom is used to quickly initialize several variables to the same value and it's equivalent to this:

```
grand = header;
parent = grand;
current = parent;
```

The assignment occurs from right-to-left, in fact the expression in the question is evaluated like this:

```
current = (parent = (grand = header));
```

This works because the result of the assignment operator actually *evaluates* to the assigned value, for example this works:

```
return x = 42;
```

In the last snippet, `42` gets assigned to `x` and then the value of `x` gets returned.

Answer (score 3):

The reference value of `header` gets assigned to each of `current`, `parent` and `grand`. Basically all the variables would refer to the same thing.

By the way, this practice is often frowned up on in real life programming.

Consider what would happen if you had code like this:

```
boolean flag = false;

if(flag = true) {
    System.out.println("true");
} else {
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

The output would be `true` here as what's really happening here is an *assignment* rather than a *comparison*.

Comment: Thanks! :) .. first time seeing this kind of referencing. :) +1 rep

Comment: What does assigning in conditional statements have to do with chained assignments...?

Comment: @BoltClock read the first sentence, the conditional statement is about the concept of variable assignments. (from my understanding) :)

Answer (score 2):

All 4 references now have the same value of header.

Comment: Brillant! thank you :) I was little confused on what was going on. +1 rep

Answer (score 1):

The statement `current = parent = grand = header` is equivalent to:

```
grand = header;
parent = grand;
current = parent;
```

Unless these are of type primitives, they all will be pointing to and sharing the same object memory location as that of `header`.

Comment: Thanks for taking some time to answer +1 rep

Answer (score 1):

reference values assigned from right to left, in primitive types values are assigned. Small example:

```
boolean first = true;
boolean second = false;

if (second = first) {
    ...
}
```

you will go into block `if` because value `first` is assigned to `second`, and then JVM will check if `second == true`.

If you write

```
if (second == first) {
    ...
}
```

You will not enter `if` block because `second != first`. That's different expressions

Comment: Thanks! for taking time to answer :) +1 rep

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator returns the value it just assigned and is right associative, so

```
a = b = c = d;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = (b = (c = d));
```

or to

```
c = d;
b = c;
a = b;
```

Note that `=` copies the value from the right into the location specified by the left side. Also note that "value" means the reference to an instance in case of `Object`-derived types, not the instance itself.